# How to reduce these mysql query to get minimum elapsed time

Tags: mysql, elapsedtime

How to reduce these MySQL query to get minimum elapsed time or reduce these query to get fast execution speed

```
SELECT relationships.bl_id 
FROM relationships 
LEFT JOIN business_data 
ON relationships.bl_id = business_data.bl_id 
LEFT JOIN business_listing 
ON business_listing.id = relationships.bl_id 
WHERE relationships.rel_id='10' or relationships.rel_id='367' 
OR relationships.rel_id='368' or relationships.rel_id='369' 
OR relationships.rel_id='370' or relationships.rel_id='371' 
OR relationships.rel_id='372' or relationships.rel_id='373' 
OR relationships.rel_id='374' or relationships.rel_id='375' 
OR relationships.rel_id='376' or relationships.rel_id='378' 
or relationships.rel_id='380' or relationships.rel_id='381' 
or relationships.rel_id='384' or relationships.rel_id='385' 
or relationships.rel_id='387' or relationships.rel_id='389' 
or relationships.rel_id='391' or relationships.rel_id='393' 
or relationships.rel_id='394' or relationships.rel_id='400' 
or relationships.rel_id='402' or relationships.rel_id='404' 
or relationships.rel_id='405' or relationships.rel_id='408' 
or relationships.rel_id='410' or relationships.rel_id='411' 
or relationships.rel_id='419' or relationships.rel_id='422' 
or relationships.rel_id='424' or relationships.rel_id='426' 
or relationships.rel_id='428' or relationships.rel_id='430' 
or relationships.rel_id='432' or relationships.rel_id='435' 
or relationships.rel_id='437' or relationships.rel_id='439' 
or relationships.rel_id='441' or relationships.rel_id='442' 
or relationships.rel_id='444' or relationships.rel_id='445' 
or relationships.rel_id='447' or relationships.rel_id='451' 
or relationships.rel_id='454' or relationships.rel_id='456' 
or relationships.rel_id='458' or relationships.rel_id='459' 
or relationships.rel_id='462' or relationships.rel_id='463' 
or relationships.rel_id='464' or relationships.rel_id='465' 
or relationships.rel_id='466' or relationships.rel_id='467' 
or relationships.rel_id='468' or relationships.rel_id='469' 
or relationships.rel_id='470' or relationships.rel_id='471' 
or relationships.rel_id='472' or relationships.rel_id='473' 
or relationships.rel_id='474' or relationships.rel_id='475' 
or relationships.rel_id='476' or relationships.rel_id='477' 
or relationships.rel_id='478' or relationships.rel_id='479' 
or relationships.rel_id='480' or relationships.rel_id='481' 
or relationships.rel_id='482' or relationships.rel_id='483' 
or relationships.rel_id='484' or relationships.rel_id='485' 
or relationships.rel_id='486' or relationships.rel_id='487' 
or relationships.rel_id='488' or relationships.rel_id='489' 
or relationships.rel_id='490' or relationships.rel_id='491' 
or relationships.rel_id='492' or relationships.rel_id='493' 
or relationships.rel_id='494' or relationships.rel_id='495' 
or relationships.rel_id='496' or relationships.rel_id='497' 
or relationships.rel_id='498' or relationships.rel_id='500' 
or relationships.rel_id='501' or relationships.rel_id='502' 
or relationships.rel_id='503' or relationships.rel_id='504' 
or relationships.rel_id='505' or relationships.rel_id='506' 
or relationships.rel_id='507' or relationships.rel_id='508' 
or relationships.rel_id='509' or relationships.rel_id='510' 
or relationships.rel_id='511' or relationships.rel_id='512' 
or relationships.rel_id='513' or relationships.rel_id='514' 
or relationships.rel_id='515' or relationships.rel_id='641' 
or relationships.rel_id='642' or relationships.rel_id='643' 
or relationships.rel_id='688' or relationships.rel_id='689' 
or relationships.rel_id='690' or relationships.rel_id='691' 
or relationships.rel_id='692' or relationships.rel_id='693' 
or relationships.rel_id='694' or relationships.rel_id='695' 
or relationships.rel_id='717' or relationships.rel_id='720' 
or relationships.rel_id='721' or relationships.rel_id='837' 
or relationships.rel_id='882' or relationships.rel_id='883' 
or relationships.rel_id='900' or relationships.rel_id='901' 
AND business_data.city = '12' and relationships.bl_id=business_data.bl_id 
AND business_listing.status = 'publish' 
order by business_data.listning_type desc limit 0 , 20
```

Comment: It is going to be hard to answer this without information on the cardinality of the tables.

Comment: Used IN operator for `relationships.rel_id`. I.e `relationships.rel_id IN (10,367,368,...,900,901)`

Comment: my current query is                                                                                      select distinct relationships.bl_id from relationships left join business_data on relationships.bl_id=business_data.bl_id left join business_listing on business_listing.id=relationships.bl_id where relationships.rel_id in ($ids) AND business_data.city = '12' and relationships.bl_id=business_data.bl_id AND business_listing.status = 'publish'

Answer (score 0):

Use This:

```
$ids=array(367,368,369,....);

select relationships.bl_id from relationships left join business_data on relationships.bl_id=business_data.bl_id left join business_listing on business_listing.id=relationships.bl_id where relationships.rel_id in ($ids) AND business_data.city = '12' and relationships.bl_id=business_data.bl_id AND business_listing.status = 'publish' order by business_data.listning_type desc limit 0 , 20
```

Comment: i reduce these query to what you say but it taking 30sec to exicute i want in a exicutio time is 0.2 sectond